# Get all mandatory fields in a xsd schema file

Tags: c#, xsd

Working against an xsd and I need to give a list of all mandatory fields to a client

Is there a way i can quickly do in c#? or use a free tool?

File is quite big I would like to avoid to do it manually

thanks

Comment: Dear fellow stackoverflow members, please stop downvoting questions for no reason! I am sad to see this kind of attitude! SO was once a friendly qna site which always supported newbies! Though OP is new, this question is so genuine, I would really appreciate it! **Before downvoting or suggesting OP to go through faq you plz go through faq once yourself! And read the third point carefully** !!

Comment: it's a good question! Keep it up! Also I would like to suggest you to update your profile with name, location and about me fields :) you can login to stackoverflow whenever you find difficulty in programming and get your queries solved ! cheers!!

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind thanks for your comment, I m new to SO and trying to play by rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try xsd2code which is a codeplex project. [See here](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) This makes classes within your code based on the Xsd format.

This is a free tool integrated into your visual studio and might help you find the necessary fields. As well that it allows you to create code easily to the xsd schema.